# Inference rule and soundness

Tags: logic

I am kind of newbie in the logic field and I have some difficulties linked to soundness and completness concepts.

Let's consider a domain composed of :

- A set of libraries $L = \{l_1, l_2, l_3\}$,
- A set of books $B = \{b_1, b_2, b_3\}$,
- A set of users $U = \{u_1, u_2, u_3\}$;

and the following relations:

- $P(x, y)$ with $x \in L$, $y \in B$ that stands for "The library $x$ has the book $y$" ;
- $Q(x, y)$ with $x \in U$, $y \in B$ that stands for "The user $x$ rents the book $y$" ;
- $R(x, y)$ with $x \in U$, $y \in L$ that stands for "The user $x$ is a member of the library $y$".

We introduce the following rule that stands for "If a library has a book and a user rent it, then this user is a member of this library"

$\forall l \in L, \forall b \in B, \forall u \in U, P(l, b) \land Q(u, b) \implies R(u, l)$

We assume that $P(l_1, b_2)$ and $Q(u_1, b_2)$ are both true. Can we prove syntaxically that $R(u_1, l_1)$ is true?

$R(u_1, l_1)$ is definitively valid because the deduction mechanisms involved are logically correct (modus ponens). Consequently, to prove that this statement is true, we have to prove that its premises are true. By definition, $P(l_1, b_2)$ and $Q(u_1, b_2)$ are true but what about our own rule: $\forall l \in L, \forall b \in B, \forall u \in U, P(l, b) \land Q(u, b) \implies R(u, l)$? Can we demonstrate that this rule is true or are we forced to accept it as an axiom ?

If we are in a logic system that is sound and complete and if we add this kind of rule, is the system still sound and complete?

Thanks

Comment: Unless you have other axioms, there is no way to prove that your rule is true, since in general, it is not.  E.g., take R as the empty relation, where R(p,l) is false always.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you have some confusion over the difference between *inference rules* and *statements*.  An inference rule is a way of deducing statements from other statements.  A statement is something which can be true (or false, or something else, depending on what language you use).  So, for instance, Modus Ponens (From "$A$" and "$A \longrightarrow B$" deduce "$B$") is an inference rule, while "For all $x$, $x = 0$ or $x \neq 0$" is a statement.

Of course, confusion can result because, in some logical systems (such as everyday speech or [higher-order logic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Higher-order_logic)), inference rules can be "equivalent to" statements.  For instance, in higher-order logic, an equivalent formulation of Modus Ponens would be the statement "For all predicates $P$ and $Q$, [$P$ and $(P \longrightarrow Q)$] $\longrightarrow Q$".

The reason that I cite confusion is that you refer to your "rule" as both an inference rule and a possible axiom; an axiom is a statement, not a rule.  The answer to your questions depend on whether you really want your "rule" to be a rule or a statement.

In the case that you want it to be an inference rule, then see Alex Kocurek's post for your answers.

In the case that you want it to be a statement, then the answer is "it depends".  Now, instead of talking about sound and complete *logic systems*, I think that you actually want to talk about sound and complete *[formal theories](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theory_%28mathematical_logic%29)*.  Basically, a theory is a set of statements (not rules) that you accept as axioms, in order to see what statements can be deduced from those axioms.  Note that the axioms do not have to valid in general for a theory to be useful: for instance, group theory is a useful theory even though the group theory axioms aren't true of every mathematical object.  Thus, the group theory axioms are "sound" when considered as a theory but unsound when considered as a set of inference rules.

Although there is no definition of soundness for theories, there are related concepts.  Generally, a theory is said to be *consistent* if its axioms do not contradict each other.  So, if you add your "rule" to a consistent theory as an axiom, then the resulting theory will be consistent if and only if your "rule" does not contradict the existing theory.
Generally, a theory is said to be *complete* if, for every statement $\alpha$ in the language, either $\alpha$ is true in the theory or $\neg \alpha$ is true in the theory.
So, if you have a consistent and complete theory, then your "rule" will already be either true or false in the theory.  If your "rule" is true in the theory, then adding it will do nothing and the theory will remain consistent and complete; if your rule is false in the theory, then adding it will make the theory inconsistent.

Comment: I was definitevely speaking about logic systems instead of formal theories. Nevertheless, it is still hard for me to see the relation between those concepts. Is the theory only the axioms's set of the logic system ? Does the theory must limits itself to syntaxically notions or could axioms includes some semantic interpretation (as in my first post) ?

Answer (score 2):

The answer to your first question is simply no, we cannot prove any of these premises are true; *all* of them must be taken as givens, or "axioms" in order to derive the conclusion $R(p_1, l_1)$. These premises are akin to "empirical facts", facts we happen to know to be true about librarians, books, people, and their relations to one another. (Side note: The fact that you use the letter "$P$" as both standing for the set of people and standing for a relation between librarians and books is potentially confusing; you'd be better off choosing a different letter, or adding a ' somewhere.)

A proof system is said to be *sound* if it cannot derive sentences that aren't valid (pardon the double negative), i.e. it can only derive sentences that are valid. If you added your premise, $\forall l \in L, \forall b \in B, \forall p \in P, P(l, b) \land Q(p, b) \implies R(p, l)$, as a *rule*, i.e. a *rule of the proof system*, then your proof system would cease to be sound, as this isn't always true (part of the confusion lies in your use of $L$, $B$, and $P$; these can't occur in the sentence unless they are *predicate letters*. But if they are, then your association of these letters to their respective sets is arbitrary, and can easily have been chosen differently to invalidate the sentence above.)

Comment: I understand why $\forall l \in L, \forall b \in B, \forall u \in U, P(l, b) \land Q(u, b) \implies R(u, l)$ is not always true if predicate letters are used. But if we only used predicate letters, how can we represent multi-domains variables (eg the fact that some variables are books but not users or library) ?

Comment: You may have to rephrase the question, but two things should be noted. First, while we sometimes say, in our metalanguage, that $B(x)$ has the intended interpretation "$x$ is a book", that still doesn't stop us from assigning different *extensions* to $B$. "Being a book" isn't a *logical* property, and so will generally be subject to such reinterpretations. Second, sometimes, when we want to *sort* the different kinds of objects in our domain out so they're not subject to reinterpretation, we can use *many-sorted* semantics. The idea is simple, but I don't have any explicit sources atm.